# Excel conditional formatting for timesheet

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I use excel to keep track of my working time.
If A1 is the "in time" and B1 is the "out time", I can easily calculate the working time as the difference.
I can also add a formula in B1, suggesting the exit time after 8 hours have expired, and later I can overwrite the cell with the actual exit time to caculate the working time.
But I also want to add conditional formatting, with gray text if the B1 cell contains the calculated exit time, turning it in black if the B1 cell contains the input of actual value.
I'm not able to find a conditional formatting rule to differentiate between a formula and a numerical input

Answer (score 0):

A condition like:

```
=LEFT(FORMULATEXT(B1),1)="="
```

Should do the job.